# display a message when the application is resized

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am new in universal apps World with C#,I have tried to make my interface responsive and to get this message when the screen is less than 600 :
[image]

is it possible to do that with triggers?
thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly use XAML in windows 10. Just specify an `gridInstruction` with your design and set its visibility as `collapsed`. Now use adaptive triggers based on screen width to set its visibility visible or collapsed.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="gridInstruction.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />                        
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="gridInstruction.Visibility" Value="Visible" />                        
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom StateTrigger for this:

```
public enum LayoutStateType
{
    TooSmall, BigEnough
}

public class LayoutTrigger : StateTriggerBase
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimalStateWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MinimalStateWidth", typeof(double), typeof(LayoutTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(600.0, OnTriggerPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LayoutStateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LayoutState", typeof(LayoutStateType), typeof(LayoutTrigger), new PropertyMetadata(LayoutStateType.Landscape, OnTriggerPropertyChanged));

    public LayoutTrigger()
    {
        Window.Current.SizeChanged += Window_SizeChanged;
        UpdateTrigger();
    }

    public double MinimalStateWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(MinimalStateWidthProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(MinimalStateWidthProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public LayoutStateType LayoutState
    {
        get
        {
            return (LayoutStateType)GetValue(LayoutStateProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(LayoutStateProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void OnTriggerPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var trigger = d as LayoutTrigger;
        trigger.UpdateTrigger();
    }

    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateTrigger();
    }

    private void UpdateTrigger()
    {
        switch (LayoutState)
        {
            case LayoutStateType.TooSmall:
                if (Window.Current.Bounds.Width <= MinimalStateWidth)
                {
                    SetActive(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    SetActive(false);
                }

                break;
            case LayoutStateType.BigEnough:
            default:
                if (Window.Current.Bounds.Width > MinimalStateWidth)
                {
                    SetActive(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    SetActive(true);
                }

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this state trigger to set visual states.

XAML usage:

```
<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <!--  Visual states reflect the application's view state  -->
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="DefaultLayout">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <triggers:LayoutTrigger LayoutState="TooSmall" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="PortraitLayout">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <triggers:LayoutTrigger LayoutState="BigEnough" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
```

In the 'too small' visual state, hide whatever you want to hide and show your message